# How to connect custom Keras layer with multiple outputs

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I defined a custom Keras layer custom_layer with two outputs: output_1 and output_2. Next, I want two independent layers A and B to connect to output_1 and output_2 respectively. How to implement this kind of network?

[image: Network sketch map:]

Comment: Your question is not clear, why output_1 is different to output_2?
Maybe you want to extract ouput_1 after layerA and output_2 after layer b?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the custom layer?

Answer (score 0):

If the custom layer has two output tensors (i.e. it returns a list of output tensors) when applied on one input, then:

```py
custom_layer_output = CustomLayer(...)(input_tensor)

layer_a_output = LayerA(...)(custom_layer_output[0])
layer_b_output = LayerB(...)(custom_layer_output[1])
```

But if it is applied on two different input tensors, then:

```py
custom_layer = CustomLayer(...)
out1 = custom_layer(input1)
out2 = custom_layer(input2)

layer_a_output = LayerA(...)(out1)
layer_b_output = LayerB(...)(out2)

# alternative way
layer_a_output = LayerA(...)(custom_layer.get_output_at(0))
layer_b_output = LayerB(...)(custom_layer.get_output_at(1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if there are some layers before custom_layer? e.g. custom_layer = CustomLayer(...)(previous_layers)

Comment: @Tian To make sure I understand your question correctly: do you mean your custom layer has been applied on two different input tensors? or does it have two outputs when applied on one input tensor?

Comment: custom layer has some layers before it, and it has two outputs

Answer (score 0):

Using the keras api mode you can create any network architecture.
In your case a possible solution is

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(100,1))
custom_layer = Dense(10)(input_layer)

# layer A model
layer_a = Dense(10, activation='relu')(custom_layer)
output1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(layer_a)

# layer B model
layer_b = Dense(10, activation='relu')(custom_layer)
output1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(layer_b)

# define model input and output
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[output1, output2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras supports having multiple output layers in your custom layer. There is a [merge](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/10939), which will update the documentation soon.
The basic idea is to work with lists. Everithing you have to reutrn in your custom layer (like layers and shape) you have to return as lists of them.

If you implement your custom layer in the right way the rest is simple:

```
output_1, output_2 = custom_layer()(input_layer)
layer_a_output = layer_a()(output_1)
layer_b_output = layer_b()(output_2)
```